# Forzar descarga de archivo csv desde jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv, download

Tengo un código que uso para generar un archivo csv y descargarlo del servidor a mi máquina, funciona de maravilla cuando ejecuto en mi máquina con Xampp, pero cuando lo subo al servidor no funciona. Imagino que debe ser algún tema de seguridad, pero no encuentro la forma de resolverlo.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
$("#exportar_button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
                url:"exportar_csv.php",
                method:'POST',
                data:{colegio:Colegio[cParam]},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.href = data;
                    let hoy = new Date();
                    fileName = "miembros_" + Colegio[cParam] + "_" + String(hoy.getDate()).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + String(hoy.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0') + '-' + hoy.getFullYear() + ".csv";
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    a.download = fileName;
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    a.remove();
                },              
            });
    });
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Revisa la consola en busca de errores. En la pregunta tampoco queda claro lo que quieres hacer, si es pasar un `.csv` del cliente al servidor o viceversa. Pulsa en [edit] para aclarar el problema.

Comment: gracias, disculpa que no respondiera antes, tuve algunos problemas en estos días y estuve desconectada. ¿Cómo puedo buscar errores?, lo que ocurre es que el archivo se genera y se guarda bien en el servidor, pero no se dscarga a mi máquina

Comment: me explico, el archivo exportar_csv.php se encarga de consultar la base de datos y crear, en el servidor, el archivo csv, eso funciona bien, el código en success es lo que pareciera no ejecutarse. Cuando lo pruebo con Xampp en mi servidor local si lo ejecuta bien, y el archivo termina en mi directorio de descarga, pero si lo ejecuto desde el servidor remoto no lo descarga